# AJAX, setJSONStructKey Issues with multiple sets of data

Tags: ajax, json, coldfusion

I'm working to create an autosuggest and am having problems getting the data to display correctly for the JQUERY plugin.

I have a table full of `customers(customerID,fName,lName)`

I need to create a JSON response like this:

```
[{"id":"856","name":"House"},
 {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
 {"id":"1048","name":"Dollhouse"},
 {"id":"1113","name":"Full House"}
]
```

Right now my code in Coldfusion looks like this:

`Query - sel_Customers.cfm`

```
<cfset newAjax.setJSONStructKey(key="id", value="#sel_Customers.customerID#")>
<cfset newAjax.setJSONStructKey(key="name", value="#sel_Customers.fName#")>
```

This results in the response:

```
[{"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","name":"Howard","id":"1","returncode":"0"}]
```

Which displays only 1 record and not 3. Is there a way in Coldfusion to setup the JSONStructKey like required and pasted above?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing this in either the CF8 or CF9 documentation.  Am I overlooking it, or is this a custom CFC (or similar) you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly does your setJSONStructKey, but suppose you need *array of structures*.

Hardcoded example:

```
<cfset json = [] />

<cfset customer = {} />
<cfset customer["id"] = "856" />
<cfset customer["name"] = "House" />
<cfset ArrayAppend(json, customer) />

<cfset customer = {} />
<cfset customer["id"] = "1035" />
<cfset customer["name"] = "Desperate Housewives" />
<cfset ArrayAppend(json, customer) />

<cfoutput>
#SerializeJSON(json)#
</cfoutput>
```

So output will be the following:

```
[{"id":856.0,"name":"House"},{"id":1035.0,"name":"Desperate Housewives"}]
```

Using the cfloop:

```
<cfset json = [] />

<cfloop query="sel_Customers">
    <cfset customer = {} />
    <cfset customer["id"] = sel_Customers.customerID />
    <cfset customer["name"] = sel_Customers.fName />
    <cfset ArrayAppend(json, customer) />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
#SerializeJSON(json)#
</cfoutput>
```

NOTICE: be aware of [this floating numbers issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853653/hidden-features-of-coldfusion/1868242#1868242) with SerializeJSON.